# Programming language metatheory in Lean 4?

Tags: lean, lean4, metatheory

I'm looking for developments of programming language metatheory done in Lean 4. We have a calculus with a lot of mutually recursive judgements and we want to formalise its denotational semantics.

Proofs of the usual properties like weakening, substitution, are the most important, but other things (like denotational semantics or logical relations) are also of interest. It's important for us to see how other people handle languages with mutually recursive judgements (eg, in dependent type theory the judgemental equality and typing are mutually recursive).

Comment: Internet points are nice, but I’m actually interested in the answer to this!

Comment: What sort of denotational semantics is it?

Comment: Would [Iris](https://iris-project.org/) be the sort of thing you interested in?  It is in Coq, but there is a [Lean 4 port of Iris](https://github.com/leanprover-community/iris-lean).  Also, why restrict the question to Lean 4?  Do you want ready to go code you can copy, or just ideas you can borrow?  If the latter, you might find a lot more in Coq.

Comment: Obviously there's a fair amount of logic in Lean, since the independence of CH was formalized. Does that help?

Answer (score 5):

We've been developing the metatheory of SSA based programs at https://github.com/opencompl/ssa/. In particular, we develop:

- An intrinsically well-typed encoding of [SSA+Regions](https://github.com/opencompl/ssa/blob/main/SSA/Core/Framework.lean#L52-L65)
- A mechanized [peephole rewriter](https://github.com/opencompl/ssa/blob/main/SSA/Core/Framework.lean#L1142-L1153) and an associated proof of correctness.
- A mechanized [dead code elimination](https://github.com/opencompl/ssa/blob/main/SSA/Projects/DCE/DCE.lean) pass.
- A work-in-progress, mechanized [common subexpression elimination](https://github.com/opencompl/ssa) pass.
- Formal semantics for compiler IRs such as an [LLVM style IR for low-level bitvector computations](https://github.com/opencompl/ssa/blob/9d775df83acb6181664188ebe3072d12797e39b1/SSA/Projects/InstCombine/Base.lean#L4), and a semantics for the primitives necessary to express fully homomorphic encryption as [particular quotients of polynomial rings](https://github.com/opencompl/ssa/blob/main/SSA/Projects/FullyHomomorphicEncryption/Basic.lean#L208-L214).

Answer (score 3):

Eventually we went ahead and did a bunch of metatheory in Lean 4 anyhow.

My work with my PhD student [Jad Ghalayini](https://github.com/imbrem) on [explicit refinement types (at ICFP 2023)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3607837) was [formalised in Lean 4 here](https://gitlab.com/explicit-refinement-types/lean4-formalization). The formalisation is decently large, though not enormous, weighing in at 16 KLOC or so (with plenty of tactics). It has a intrinsically-typed representation of a fairly complicated type theory, with a proof of syntactic substitution, a denotational semantics, and a proof that syntactic and semantic substitution agree with each other, as well as a bunch of proofs about the equational theory.

The high-order bit is that Lean 4 was not ready to be used for programming languages semantics when we started, but that it basically is ready now. Every time that Jad ran into trouble (eg, the pattern compiler exploding on his language) the Lean developers were quite responsive and fixed the problems very quickly.

The main outstanding problem is that as of August 2023, Lean 4 handled big mutually-recursive datatypes terribly. We ended up using the usual trick of turning our mutually-recursive family of datatypes into one big inductive type with an extra index saying which member of the family each constructor belonged to. That worked well enough not to stop us, even if it is a little hacky.

EDIT: Jad tells me that the other big problem he ran into is that the Lean VS Code plugin leaks tons of memory when working with large inductive proofs: too much stuff is cached and memory usage goes up linearly over time. He used to restart the plugin every 20-30 minutes, until he realised he could just set the swap space really big. Because the cached stuff was never touched ever again, it would swap to disk and never be heard from again. Again, all this is as of the first half of 2023 -- it seems like the kind of thing that will get fixed sooner or later.

Comment: Very cool! What did you use to represent binding? De Bruijn? Or was it "intrinsically typed" like a shallow embedding?

Answer (score 2):

An exciting direction is the metatheory of Lean 4 itself.

In Sebastian Ullrich's dissertation [An Extensible Theorem Proving Frontend](https://lean-lang.org/papers/thesis-sebastian.pdf), he formalizes the semantics of Lean 4's do notation in Lean 4 including [a correctness theorem](https://lean-lang.org/papers/thesis-sebastian.pdf#section.5.6).  The full Lean 4 formalization is in [appendix B](https://lean-lang.org/papers/thesis-sebastian.pdf#appendix.B).

More recently, Mario Carneiro's [lean4lean](https://github.com/digama0/lean4lean) implements a Lean 4 kernel in pure Lean 4.  Practically, this can act as an external type checker (which is only about 1/3 slower than the C++ kernel), and could be used in the future as Lean's default kernel (moving more of Lean's implementation to Lean code).  Moreover, since the kernel is written in pure Lean (almost no `partial` code, using a timeout to avoid logical paradoxes), lean4lean's code can be directly analyzed in Lean.

Mario's [long-term plan](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113488-general/topic/Lean4Lean.3A.20Lean.204.20kernel.20in.20Lean/near/396413039) seems to be to formalize [his thesis](https://github.com/digama0/lean-type-theory/releases) in Lean, including a formalization of Lean's type theory $\mathsf{LeanTT}$ in Lean, a formal proof that lean4lean is a correct checker for $\mathsf{LeanTT}$, and a formalization that there is a set-theoretic model of $\mathsf{LeanTT}$.  Altogether this would provide a formal proof (in Lean 4) of the consistency of Lean's type theory and the correctness of its kernel.